# Sequelize and MySQL with MAMP, I get an error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I get a problem with Sequelize for Express (node.js). I try to connect an MySQL database from MAMP Mac with Sequelize for express but it doesn't work, I don't understand why but I got an error:

Maybe I have to edit the MySQL configuration file for comment "MAMP_skip-networking_MAMP" but I don't find the MySQL Conf file for MAC...

My code:

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

var db = new Sequelize('express', 'root', 'root', {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '3306'
});

var Project = db.define('Project', {
    date: Sequelize.DATE,
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT
});

var project = Project.build({
    date: new Date(),
    title: 'Mon premiéé projeétçç!!',
    description: 'dsqlmdskq lkqskl ksqlmk lsmdqklm'
});

project
    .save();
```

Comment: sure that credentials are correct and that the tables already exist?

Comment: I haven't create the tables, but if I create the tables, do I have to add the primary key?

Comment: just use [sequelize.sync](http://sequelizejs.com/#models-sync) before you create instances.

Comment: Thank's it works with sync() function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize"); 
var db = new Sequelize('express', 'root', 'root', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '3306' 
});

var Project = db.define('Project', {
  date: Sequelize.DATE,
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT 
});

db.sync().success(function() {
  var project = Project.build({
    date: new Date(),
    title: 'Mon premiéé projeétçç!!',
    description: 'dsqlmdskq lkqskl ksqlmk lsmdqklm' 
  });

  project.save();
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using port `8889` instead of `3306`.

Comment: @NguyenTanDat that's the [default port for MySQL on MAMP](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/Preferences/Ports/)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, finally I figured out my problem is I didn't restart MamP after changing port. Everything works now!